# ACF Fields - Array Loop - IF Statement

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields

I am using this code that returns an array:

```
$values = get_field('sp_specialism', $prev_id);var_dump($values);
```

The output of the array is:

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(4) "Asia" [1]=> string(6) "Canada" [2]=> string(9) "Caribbean" }
```

I am trying to loop through the array and output Asia Canada Caribbean as list items

```
if($values) { echo '<ul>'; foreach($values as $value) { echo '<li>' . $value . '</li>'; } echo '</ul>'; }
```

However my if statement is erroring out. Not sure why this happens.

I am using this within another piece of code like this:

```
$string = "<span class=\"bkcards-exp\">" . get_field('sp_location', $prev_id) . "</span><span class=\"bkcards-left\">" . if($values) { echo '<ul>'; foreach($values as $value) { echo '<li>' . $value . '</li>'; } echo '</ul>'; } . "</span>"
```

Comment: Can you specify the error?

Comment: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)

Comment: I am using this inside a $string variable. could that be the issue ?

Comment: this error may mean that you are missing a semicolon in your code? What do you mean by $string variable?

Comment: ok I have added the full code that this statement is being used in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't concatenate an `if` statement with a string. Instead, you can divide the string into multiple different statements as shown in the following snippet.

```
$string = '<span class="bkcards-exp">' . 
               get_field('sp_location', $prev_id) . 
          '</span><span class="bkcards-left">';

if($values) { 
    $string .= '<ul>'; 
    foreach($values as $value) { 
        $string .= '<li>' . $value . '</li>'; 
    } 
    $string .= '</ul>';
}

$string .= '</span>';
```

Comment: But I need the output to be assigned to $string because it's being used in another part of the code

Comment: Using echo is not what I would like here....